# three js sphere device controls limit camera rotation

Tags: three.js

using three js to create a sphere and adding a 360 deg picture inside. 
now, the photo has a black hole at the bottom.

is there a way to limit camera rotation and prevent user from seeing the very bottom of the sphere?

I have this for camera:

```
this.controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(this.camera, true);
```

- also looking for a solution while using OrbitControls.

`this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.element);`

target devices: mobiles support webgl.

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

From the source of the `THREE.OrbitControls`. As you can see you can limit the controls rotation.

```
// How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
// Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

// How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
// If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
this.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians
```

Comment: thanks! know if this is possible to achieve on DeviceOrientationControls?

Comment: did not see any such properties on DeviceOrientationControls.